# Authenticate to Azure Function from within App

Tags: azure, facebook-c#-sdk, azure-functions

I'm using Facebook Authentication for my Azure Function App, it works fine if I navigate to a function within the browser.  I would like to invoke my functions from within an app but an unsure how to perform the authentication.

At current I am attempting to use the Facebook Client, this returns me an access_token that I am then forwarding to the ".auth/login/facebook/callback" function within my function app.  Unfortunately that's as far as I can get, doing this via a GET returns HTML with JavaScript in, and doing it via a POST redirects back to Facebook.

What I really need is the cookie created by the azure function, AppServiceAuthSession, I believe I can then use this to call the functions.

Edit: I don't think i can just use the cookie, like I said above so I need to authenticate properly.

Nick.

Comment: What type of client are you using? How are you sending the access_token to the function -- in the URL? Is that access_token the one you get directly from Facebook?

Comment: I tried the Facebook C# client and tried using it in my function urls, and also passing it to the ".auth/login/facebook/callback", neither worked.  I sent it as a query parameter, i.e. https://myfunctionapp/api/foobar?access_token=abcd  Also this morning I tried the MobileServiceClient used for App Services, but I couldn't get it to work, Facebook login box appears, then after authentication it says that it has network issues.

Comment: I should comment I also tried returning the authorization code, also obtainable from the Facebook C# SDK with no luck.  Yup both come from Facebook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get the tokens passed along to the function app while using the Facebook Javascript SDK (I wasn't having any luck with the C# one) -- maybe this will get you moving in the right direction.

The client:

1. Performs the login to Facebook, which returns an `accessToken`.
2. Client needs to exchange this `accessToken` for an 'App Service Token'. It does this by making a POST to `https://{app}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook` with the content `{ "access_token" : "{token from Facebook}" }`. This will return back an `authenticationToken`.
3. Use that `authenticationToken` in a header named `x-zumo-auth`. Make all requests to your function app using that header.

From within your function app, you should then have the current Principal set to that logged in user.

Comment: That worked great, only thing I noticed was that getting the email claim no longer worked, but the function is running so there's probably another reason for that.  I'll investigate.  Many thanks for your help.